# Converting String to DateTime in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I need to insert the datetime value entered from the HTML form using PHP into the MySQL database. However I receive the Incorrect datetime value error each time I try to execute the code below,

```
$rosterstartdate=$_GET['rosterstartdate'];
$rosterenddate=$_GET['rosterenddate'];

//$date = date_create_from_format('d/M/Y:H:i:s', $rosterstartdate);
//$date->getTimestamp();
//echo $date;

$date = strtotime($rosterstartdate);
echo date('d/M/Y H:i:s', $date);

    // echo DATE_FORMAT($rosterstartdate,"%Y%m%d %H%i%s");

    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
    if($con==true){
        mysql_select_db("attendance_db",$con);
        $query="insert into tblroster values(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$rosterteam','$rostershifts','$date','$rosterenddate')";
```

I have tried using each of the different techniques above to do the conversion but it does not work. Any ideas on how this could be inserted

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?  Would you post the output of 'describe tblroster;' ?

Comment: The date format should be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: Incorrect datetime value: '1341926751' for column 'rosterstartdate' at row 1

Comment: What is the column type of 'rosterstartdate'?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
```

Instead of echoing it out, use that code to format the date.

However, it looks like what you really want is this:

```
$rosterstartdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($rosterstartdate));
$rosterenddate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($rosterenddate));
```

This way you can just reference those two variables in your query string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to format it if you have a unixtime use [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime),
change your query as

```
    $rosterstartdate=$_GET['rosterstartdate'];
$rosterenddate=$_GET['rosterenddate'];

//$date = date_create_from_format('d/M/Y:H:i:s', $rosterstartdate);
//$date->getTimestamp();
//echo $date;

$date = strtotime($rosterstartdate);

    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
    if($con==true){
        mysql_select_db("attendance_db",$con);
        $query="insert into tblroster values(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$rosterteam','$rostershifts',FROM_UNIXTIME($date),'$rosterenddate')";
```